# How to push JSON element names and values into a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am dealing with a `Json` object with an a priori partly unknown structure. I am not sure whether I can use the deserialising object method, because I cannot predict the exact structure length and naming I wish to target.

I simply know that the structure skeleton (looking at the `Json` previewer) is going to be like:

```
[JSON]
    [meta] 
        metaname1: metavalue1
        ...
        metanameN: metavalueN
    [target]
        [0]
            targetname1: targetvalue1
            ...
            targetnameP: targetvalueP
```

The actual extracted structure is as follows:

```
{[meta, {
  "limit": 100,
  "offset": 0,
  "count": 1,
  "total": 1
}]}
{[target, [
  {
    "open": 173.99,
    "high": 175.46,
    "low": 172.675,
    "last": 175.38,
    "close": 173.66,
    "volume": 607334.0,
    "date": "2023-10-05T21:00:00+02:00",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "exchange": "IEXG"
  }
]]}
```

I would like to skip the 'meta' node and focus on the 'target' node and push the series of keys and values (targetname1, targetvalue1),..., (targetnameP, targetvalueP) into a dictionary. I have loaded the `Json` object using `Newtonsoft.Json` library after reading the data from internet at a given 'address'.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync(address);
    using (HttpResponseMessage message = response.Result)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = message.Content)
        {
            string jsonData = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed next.

---

**Addendum**

---

Now I am trying this but I am still stuck.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonData = @"
            {[meta, {
               "limit": 100,
               "offset": 0,
               "count": 1,
               "total": 1
            }]}
            {[target, [
              {
                "open": 173.99,
                "high": 175.46,
                "low": 172.675,
                "last": 175.38,
                "close": 173.66,
                "volume": 607334.0,
                "date": "2023-10-05T21:00:00+02:00",
                "symbol": "AAPL",
                "exchange": "IEXG"
              }
            ]]}";

        Dictionary<string, object> jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
        object jsonSubData = jsonDict["target"];
    }
}
```

I am failing to get 'jsonSubData' into another dictionary.

---

**Is it an efficient solution?**

---

I have come up with this. It seems to work. I am not sure it is the most efficient solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonData = @"Same structure as before";

        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        JObject jsonSubObj = jsonObj["data"].Values<JObject>().First();

        Dictionary<string, string> jsonDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (JProperty property in jsonSubObj.Properties())
            jsonDict.Add(property.Name, property.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be far easier to post the actual json for people to play around with instead of json previewer thingy.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need a JObject ?  Why can't you deserialise to a simple class?

Comment: the easiest way is to deserialize the json into `Dictionary<string, object>`, then you can work things from there.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith. Not sure either. I was simply investigating what could be obtained from the `JObject` class.

Comment: @iSR5. I was struggling because I was doing this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonData);`, which returned an exception. Doing as you put it, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);`, indeed returns the two-levelled ('meta', 'target') node structure I am after. Then, I can in turn access the 'target' part, which, I presume, I need to deserialise again into another dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the JSON.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith. Done!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the json root will always contain `meta` and `target` properties. If so, you can do this:

```
public sealed class DataContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("meta")]
    public Dictionary<string, object>? Meta { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("target")]
    public Dictionary<string, object>[]? Data { get; set; }
}
```

then, you just do this :

```
string json = @"{""meta"":{""limit"":100,""offset"":0,""count"":1,""total"":1},""target"":[{""open"":173.99,""high"":175.46,""low"":172.675,""last"":175.38,""close"":173.66,""volume"":607334.0,""date"":""2023-10-05T21:00:00+02:00"",""symbol"":""AAPL"",""exchange"":""IEXG""}]}";

DataContainer? data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(json);
```

now you can access the `Data` property, and iterate over all its elements (objects).

if you're using `System.Text.Json`, then you just change the following :

```
JsonPropertyAttribute         -> JsonPropertyNameAttribute 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject -> JsonSerializer.Deserialize
```

if your json root has more keys than the example above, and you only want `target`, then you could omit the `Meta` property, then use the `JsonSerializerSettings` and set the `MissingMemberHandling` to `MissingMemberHandling.Ignore`, this will ensure you only deserialize whatever you provide in the `DataContainer` class.

Comment: Many thanks @iSR5. Your answer is very neat, smart and helpful.